# Complexity of famous iterative task

Tags: time, time-complexity

We have array of size n with n  integers in it.The task is to find the first larger element after a given one and if there is none return -1;
FOR example input 7 2 4 6 16  output: 16,4,6,-1
**Whats the average complexity with naive double for-cycle solution?**

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: I expect it to be somewhere in the order of n*log n  naively because i calculate the chance to find it in the first element is 50% on average, on the second 25% on the third 12.5% and so on so its O(1)*50%+
O(2)*25%+ ... so on  euqlas log n for each element. I've made a general formula for the ith element but i dont know advanced math and cant calculate it

Comment: Why would it take a "double for-cycle"? I struggle to see how even a "naive" solution would resort to using two for-loops. Anyway, the time complexity is trivially `O(n)`, no need for all of this complicated analysis based on percentages.

Comment: for all elements i thought was obvious